# Display new button on onClick(); ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to the reactJS and I'm making simple To-do App,I already implemented Edit and Delete and now I'm stuck on Pagination,I'm trying to display new button on certain circumstances but It's not working and I'm confused. The problem is It is not displaying a new button

```
class App extends Component {
state = {
    inputValue: '',
    todos: [],
    currentPage:1,
    pageCount:1,
};

setPageCount = () => {
        let {todos} = this.state
      this.setState({pageCount: Math.ceil(todos.length / 5)})
        console.log('--------this.state.pageCount', this.state.pageCount );
}

renderPagination = () => {
    let {pageCount} = this.state
    for(let i=0; i<= pageCount; i++) {
        return <button onClick={this.paginationDisplay()}>
            {pageCount}
        </button>
    }
}

paginationDisplay = () => {
    console.log('Hello world')

addItem = () => {
        let {inputValue, todos} = this.state
        this.setState({todos: [...todos, {inputValue, id: uuidv4()}]})
        this.setPageCount()
        this.renderPagination()

    }

render() {
        return <div className={"App"}>
            <div className="App-header">
                <h2>Welcome to To-Do List App</h2>
            </div>
            <input onChange={this.handleInputValue} name={''} type='text'/>
            <button onClick={() => this.addItem()} className={'btn btn-primary'}>Add</button>
            <ul>
                {
                    this.state.todos.map(todoItem => <ListItem
                        key={todoItem.id}
                        todoItem={todoItem}
                        deleteItem={this.deleteItem}
                        editItem={this.editItem}
                        submitEdit={this.submitEdit}
                    />)
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    };
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It is not Displaying the new button

Comment: can you show your `render` method?

Comment: render() {
  return <div className={"App"}>
   <div className="App-header">
    <h2>Welcome to To-Do List App</h2>
   </div>
   <input onChange={this.handleInputValue} name={''} type='text'/>
   <button onClick={() => this.addItem()} className={'btn btn-primary'}>Add</button>
   <ul>
    {
     this.state.todos.map(todoItem => <ListItem
      key={todoItem.id}
      todoItem={todoItem}
      deleteItem={this.deleteItem}
      editItem={this.editItem}
      submitEdit={this.submitEdit}
     />)
    }
   </ul>
  </div>
 };
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move renderPaginator function to render like this.

```js
addItem = () => {
    let { inputValue, todos } = this.state;
    this.setState({ todos: [...todos, { inputValue, id: uuid() }] });
    this.setPageCount();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={"App"}>
        <div className="App-header">
          <h2>Welcome to To-Do List App</h2>{" "}
        </div>
        <input onChange={this.handleInputValue} name={""} type="text" />{" "}
        <button onClick={() => this.addItem()} className={"btn btn-primary"}>
          Add
        </button>
        <ul>
          {" "}
          {this.state.todos.map(todoItem => (
            <div
              key={todoItem.id}
              todoItem={todoItem}
              deleteItem={this.deleteItem}
              editItem={this.editItem}
              submitEdit={this.submitEdit}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
        {this.renderPagination()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Every time you update the state using setState function render function is called.